# Symfony 1.4 editing routing Issue

Tags: php, symfony, routes

I'm working on a symfony 1.4 based project and I was trying to editing the URL so to make them more user-friendly and have a good interpretation by the search engine so to make a good SEO (even if I'm not a SEO, i only know the fundamentals and trying to meet Google requirements).
So after reading the documentation I understood that first of all I had to edit routing.yml (in /apps/frontend/config/), so this is what I've tried:
this was the routing

```
object_show:
  url:  /:sf_culture/object/show/:slug/:object_id
  param: {module: object, action: show}
```

I want that it lloks like this:

```
object_show:
  url: /:sf_cultural/opera/:slug/:object_id
```

But after editing it and saving I get nothing when i try to access the url inserting it manually.

I'm literraly getting crazy from a week and can't find any solution, so please some symfony master can help me out?

Thank you very much

Comment: `sf_cultural` ?!? What is this ? Why did you remove the colon before it and change the variable name ? And what does "opera" refer to ?

Comment: sf_cultural is the component which recognize the language to show in. I've not removed :, it was removed while writing here. opera refers to an artistic object such as painting or sculpture, so i generalized it with opera instead of object that was not very usefull.